# Flutter: Using a (Future) http post request in ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

in one of my ChangeNotifier, if have an authentificate method. This is a method, that
gets an auth - token with a Future gettoken function and then sets the some values of the LoginController class.

When I call the **.authentificate** using **Provider.of()**, I think, I change the result of
getToken from a **Future<String>** to a simple **<String>** (via **.then(...)**)
and then try to evaluate wether the token was received or not.
Unfortunately,
the last thing that is printed is "API Authentification success" from the get **getToken** function and not **Evaluating the token**.
What do I do wrong here?

```
class LoginController extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pagenr          = 0;
  bool is_logged_in   = false;
  String token_string = "";

  void change_page_nr(int item) {
    pagenr = item;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void authenticate(String username,String password) {
    getToken(username, password).then((String result){token_string = result;});
    
    // Code seems to stop working here, at least nothing is printed or changed even though
    // the token request exits without an error.

    print("Evaluating the token");
    if (token_string.length > 0) {
      print("Logging in succesful!");
      is_logged_in = true;
      int pagenr   = 1;
    } else {
      print("Logging in failed!");
      is_logged_in = false;
      int pagenr   = 0;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

with

```
Future<String> getToken(String username, String password) async {
  print("TokenURL in api_connection.dart");
  print(_tokenURL);

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(_tokenURL),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      }
      )
);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("API Authentification successful!");
    return json.decode(response.body)["token"];
  } else {
    print(json.decode(response.body).toString());
    print("API Authentification failed");
    return "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `authenticate` function to asynchronous and await `getToken`.

```
  Future<void> authenticate(String username,String password) async {
    final token_string = await getToken(username, password);
    
    ...

    notifyListeners();
  }
```